# unity3d nft marker how to make

Tags: unity-game-engine, design-patterns, marker, artoolkit

Helo Guys,

I've ran into a very deep trouble within a very long time of googling havent found answers. so here it is.

i'm trying to make Augmented Reality without any commercial plugins i have to pay for (vuforia) in unity3d, this program i will send to android.

i've messing around with vuforia, kudan, and other, but i want more power with my apps i can control myself.

i want to make nft marker based augmented reality, i've tried artoolkit, but the explanation and samples only get into generating .fset .iset .fset3 file but it stopped there, no info about generating the .patt file needed nor info about where to put those dataset files.

i've tried using openspace3d, but also only generating fset iset file, no .patt file.

my question is : how to generate .patt file, and if i have the dataset file (iset fset fset3) how do i proceed on creating my own custom nft marker augmented reality in unity3d?

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you have a slight misconception of marker files for Artoolkit.

Artoolkit knows two types of markers. Patterns and NFT markers.

1. The pattern (.patt) files are for the so-called framemarkers.
2. The fset(.iset,.fset,.fset3) files are for the NFT markers. You don't need a pattern file for NFT markers.

For a comprehensive list with examples of AR-Marker you can look [here](https://anymotion.com/en/wissensgrundlagen/augmented-reality-marker).

So in your case, you only need the fset files.

**Training:**

For training, you can use the description and the tools from [this site](https://artoolkit.org/documentation/doku.php?id=3_Marker_Training:marker_nft_training) and [this site](https://artoolkit.org/documentation/doku.php?id=3_Marker_Training:marker_nft_utilities). But be warned. Finding good values is a bit of a trial and error.

**Usage:**

If you haven't already done so, download the Unity package from [this page](https://artoolkit.org/download-artoolkit-sdk). If you're using windows you can also download the windows tool on the same page.

That package comes with several example scenes. Including TwoNFTMarker. ( under Assets/Artoolkit5-unity/Example Scenes). Open that and look at the ARToolkit Object. In the inspector, you will find two ARMarker scripts with two NFT Markers already configured. To replace the standard NFT Marker with your own you can put your own fset files under Assets/StreamingAssets and restart unity. After that, you should be able to choose your files in the marker script.

That being said. NFT markers work considerably worse than in vuforia and kudan. There is a reason why this a "paid" frameworks.

I hope this helps.